# Multiple image inference for mask-rcnn runs ~10x slower than faster-rcnn for the same image size

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I successfully retrained mask-rcnn and faster-rcnn models with my own custom dataset and I want to run inference for multiple images. I modified the single image inference function from the demo with the code below. I got the following result if I used retrained faster-rcnn resnet101
[image]
and the following result if I used retrained mask-rcnn resnet101
[image]
The following if I run with faster-rcnn inception-resnet
[image]
and the following with mask-rcnn inception-resnet
[image]
All images have resolution of 1024x768. Please help whether this is the right behavior or not. Thanks

The following function is the one that I modified from the demo

```
def run_inference_for_multiple_images(images, graph):
  with graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        output_dict_array = []
        dict_time = []
        for image in images:
            # Get handles to input and output tensors
            ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
            all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
            tensor_dict = {}
            for key in ['num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
                'detection_classes', 'detection_masks']:
                tensor_name = key + ':0'
                if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
                    tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
                        tensor_name)
            if 'detection_masks' in tensor_dict:
                detection_boxes = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_boxes'], [0])
                detection_masks = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_masks'], [0])
                # Reframe is required to translate mask from box coordinates to image coordinates and fit the image size.
                real_num_detection = tf.cast(tensor_dict['num_detections'][0], tf.int32)
                detection_boxes = tf.slice(detection_boxes, [0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1])
                detection_masks = tf.slice(detection_masks, [0, 0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1, -1])
                detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
                    detection_masks, detection_boxes, image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
                detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(
                    tf.greater(detection_masks_reframed, 0.5), tf.uint8)
                # Follow the convention by adding back the batch dimension
                tensor_dict['detection_masks'] = tf.expand_dims(
                    detection_masks_reframed, 0)
            image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

            # Run inference
            start = time.time()
            output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
                                   feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})
            end = time.time()
            print('inference time : {}'.format(end-start))

            # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate
            output_dict['num_detections'] = int(output_dict['num_detections'][0])
            output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict[
                'detection_classes'][0].astype(np.uint8)
            output_dict['detection_boxes'] = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
            output_dict['detection_scores'] = output_dict['detection_scores'][0]
            if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
                output_dict['detection_masks'] = output_dict['detection_masks'][0]

            output_dict_array.append(output_dict)
            dict_time.append(end-start)
return output_dict_array, dict_time
```

The following is a piece of code to run the function

```
batch_size = 10
chunks = len(diff_files) // batch_size + 1
ave_time = []
for i in range(chunks):
    batch = diff_files[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
    images = []
    files = []
    proc_time = []
    for file in batch:
        image_path = os.path.join(subdir_path, file)
        print('Reading file {}'.format(image_path))
        image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        image_np = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        images.append(image_np)
        files.append(file)

    output_dicts, out_time = run_inference_for_multiple_images(images, detection_graph)
    print('length of output_dicts is : {}'.format(len(output_dicts)))
    if len(output_dicts) == 0:
        break

    for idx in range(len(output_dicts)):
        output_dict = output_dicts[idx]
        image_np = images[idx]
        file = files[idx]
        # Visualization of the results of a detection.
        start = time.time()
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          output_dict['detection_boxes'],
          output_dict['detection_classes'],
          output_dict['detection_scores'],
          category_index,
          instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
          use_normalized_coordinates=True, min_score_thresh=.5,
          line_thickness=4, skip_scores=False,
          skip_labels=False,
          skip_boxes=False)
        height, width, chan = image_np.shape

        # Saving the processed image
        image_np = cv2.cvtColor(image_np, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(result_img_path, file), image_np)
        print('Saving {}, time : {}'.format(file, time.time()-start))
        proc_time.append(time.time()-start + out_time[idx])
        # count += 1    

    if len(proc_time) != 0:
        mean_batch_time = statistics.mean(proc_time)
        print('mean processing time: {}'.format(mean_batch_time))
        ave_time.append(mean_batch_time)
    proc_time.clear()
    output_dicts.clear()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issues and the following function seems to work. The average inference time has reduced from around 3-4 seconds to 0.3-0.4 seconds per image (using resnet50 feature extractor). However, You must be careful when using this function because the assumption taken when using batch size image is **all of the images must have the same size**. Therefore, there would be an error thrown when one of the image in the batch has different sizes. Though I haven't confirmed this myself.

```
def run_inference_for_multiple_images(images, graph):
    with graph.as_default():
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            output_dict_array = []
            dict_time = []
            # Get handles to input and output tensors
            ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
            all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
            tensor_dict = {}
            for key in ['num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
                'detection_classes', 'detection_masks']:
                tensor_name = key + ':0'
                if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
                    tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(tensor_name)
            if 'detection_masks' in tensor_dict:
                detection_boxes = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_boxes'], [0])
                detection_masks = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_masks'], [0])
                # Reframe is required to translate mask from box coordinates to image coordinates and fit the image size.
                real_num_detection = tf.cast(tensor_dict['num_detections'][0], tf.int32)
                detection_boxes = tf.slice(detection_boxes, [0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1])
                detection_masks = tf.slice(detection_masks, [0, 0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1, -1])
                detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
                    detection_masks, detection_boxes, images[0].shape[0], images[0].shape[1])
                detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(tf.greater(detection_masks_reframed, 0.5), tf.uint8)
                # Follow the convention by adding back the batch dimension
                tensor_dict['detection_masks'] = tf.expand_dims(detection_masks_reframed, 0)
            image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
            for image in images:
                # Run inference
                start = time.time()
                output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict, feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})
                end = time.time()
                print('inference time : {}'.format(end - start))

                # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate
                output_dict['num_detections'] = int(output_dict['num_detections'][0])
                output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict['detection_classes'][0].astype(np.uint8)
                output_dict['detection_boxes'] = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
                output_dict['detection_scores'] = output_dict['detection_scores'][0]
                if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
                    output_dict['detection_masks'] = output_dict['detection_masks'][0]

                output_dict_array.append(output_dict)
                dict_time.append(end - start)
    return output_dict_array, dict_time
```

Comment: So you basically re-trained your model using ResNet50 ?

Comment: Yes I did, even though I retrained to several other models.

Comment: What was your conclusion ... what method worked out to be fastest with decent mAP ?

Comment: For the most accurate feature extractor, the best one is ResNet-101 while for the fastest one you could either go with ResNet-50 or Inception. You can look for the detail at https://ascelibrary.org/doi/abs/10.1061/%28ASCE%29CP.1943-5487.0000890 where I published my paper

Comment: Sorry but I can't afford to pay for it. THanks for the clarification tho